# Connecting keyboard USB-B (usb host) port to audio interface with midi out and midi in ports

Tags: audio, cable

I want to connect my Casio CT-X5000 keyboard with my audio interface.

Casio keyboard has USB host port and my audio interface has midi in and midi out ports. How do I make the connection here? I believe that the standard way would be to go from casio keyboard directly to PC, but how do I make the connection from keyboard to audio interface with midi ports?

USB-B to midi in/out adapter?

Comment: You're looking for a _USB Host_ To MIDI adapter box. They can be found in music equipment stores. With such an adapter you should be able to connect a "USB only" keyboard to another MIDI device without having a computer in between. (well the adapter box sort of works as a "computer" i.e. host)

Comment: I thought about it, but they seem to have only USB-A connection and my keyboad has USB-B out. I guess I'd use USB-B to USB-A adapter which I'd plug to this device and then go to audio interface.

Comment: In case anyone's browsing this, I just tried to solve this issue with one of these and it didn't work at all.  https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B09KH1GG3F?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details